# Convert column datatpe to ArrayType(Double) dynamically in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataFrame built from a json file in this format:

```
{"max": [10,10,10],"min":[1,1,1],"id1":[1,2], "cId":"1", ... }
```

schema of this is inferred as

```
root
 max: array, 
     element: long
 min: array
     element: long
 more columns here ...
```

Ask: I want to convert known list of columns' (like min and max) datatype from ArrayType(Long) to ArrayType(Double).
 
Things to notice:

Sometimes they are already of type ArrayType(Double) and sometimes they are just 'String' or 'Integer' type, also total column count is not fixed, there can be 'n' number of additional columns.

How can I convert these selected columns' schema at runtime after checking the datatype of these columns.

Given inputs:

Dataframe

name of the list of columns, datatype needs to be changed to ArrayType(Double).

Comment: is below solution is not working ?